# Debugging a TCP-Server

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have a C++ application that accepts TCP connections from client applications.

After a seemingly random time of running fine (days), it stops receiving followup messages from the clients and only sees the first message on each TCP connection. After a re-start all is fine again.

The trouble is, this only happens on the production server where I have to restart is as soon as it gets stuck and I have been uanble to reproduce this on a lab machine. None of the socket operations seems to return an error, that I would see in my logfile and the application is huge so I can't just post the relevant part here.

First messages keep coming through all the time, only subsequent messages aren't received after a while. Even when my application stops receiving the followup-messages, I can see them comming in with Wireshark.

Any ideas how I might find out what is happening ? What should I be looking for ?

Comment: More logging, _much_ more logging.

Comment: @Joachim: Thanks, but I am already checking all return values of all socket functions. Nothing. Anything non-obvious that should to be logged ?

Comment: The return values of _all_ system functions. Maybe add tracing to your own functions (i.e. "now entering function x"/"now leaving function x", possibly logging arguments as well).

Comment: Add more details, like are you windows or linux developer

Comment: @luskan: This happens on a Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

Any config settings used here? In the past I have put a condition on a server accept to ignore messages after 50,000 have been processed. This was to prevent run-away situations in development. This code went live on one occasion without changing the config setting to 'allow infinite messages'. The result was exactly what you describe, ok for 2-3 days, then messages sent ok, but just ignored with no errors anywhere.

This may not be the case here, but I mention it as an example of where you may have to look.

Comment: Interesting idea. Unfortunately I don't have an artifical blocking in there. Other installations run weeks or months without issues.